# React error Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression no-unused-expressions while passing props to child component

Tags: reactjs

im getting Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions while trying to pass props to child component.
fetchMovie() make axios request to api and returns a valid JSON object.
im trying to pass the object as a prop to child component and im getting this error

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchMovie } from '../actions/movies';
import { MovieItem } from './MovieItem';
import Spinner from './spinner/Spinner';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

export class Movies extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchMovie();
  }

  render() {
    const { movie } = this.props.movies;
    let movieItem;
    if (movie === null) {
      movieItem = 'loading';
    } else {
      <MovieItem movie={movie} />
    }
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="text-center"><p>{movieItem}</p></div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

Movies.propTypes = {
  movies: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  fetchMovie: PropTypes.func.isRequired
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  movies: state.movies
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchMovie })(Movies);
```

how to solve this issue? and what is the error meaning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the render method, in the `else` branch you create a `MovieItem` component, but you don't do anything with it. Looking at your code, I guess you need to assign it to `movieItem` variable, so it gets than rendered in the `p` element.

Comment: The error posted by him refers exactly to this kind of situation: the definition of a React component is compiled down to an expression by Babel, and the result of that expression (that is a JS object created by React) is assigned nowhere. The error says "no-unused-expressions" in fact.

Comment: The description of the error (Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression) is another way to tell the same thing: expression should be assigned, if you do no assignment the compiler thinks you are doing something strange and asks you if you did not meant to use an assignment or a function call